# Design asp.net web application as two separate modules for separate deployment

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I'm working on a web application that consists of two separate modules. I've finished working on module 1 of the application and right now I'm starting to work on module 2. I need to find a way that allows me to deploy the two modules separately at the customer.

For example, when doing changes to module 1 I would deploy module 1 only, when adding new features in module 2 I would deploy module 2 only.

I currently have a single project in my application which includes module 1:

- should I create a new project for module 2? If so, I'm not sure how I can create a link between them, as I will need to navigate from Module 1 to Module 2 using an aspx page or so.
- If I let them be in the same project, would that be a good design practice? Also Is there a way to still separate between the deploys?

Comment: This is pretty vague.  A good design would account for the specifics of the separation between mobile 1 & module 2, e.g. is it vertical or horizontal, are they separate web sites each with their own pages or does one module contain the pages while the other contains business logic, etc.  In general though if you want them to be separately deployable they should be separately buildable, i.e. separate projects.